# Analyzing Characters in Ubuntu

Tags: special-characters, utf-8, ascii, character-set

I need a tool that can tell me the character encodings of each visible and invisible character from a range of characters I highlight within its editor.

For example, a line break is usually `\n` in Linux, but is `\r\n` in Windows. This tool would allow me to determine which is being used in a document.

If I type a quote, using my key board, it looks like `"`. But, sometimes people will copy and paste text from a tool like Microsoft Word, and it will have quotes that look like `”`. Here's those two different quotes side by side respectively: **`"` `”`** (I hope you can see the difference.)

I a web page that sends an email notification from a form that gets submitted. Here's how it was suppose to look in the receive email:
[image]

**And here is how it actually looked in someone's Microsoft Outlook:**

[image]

It didn't look this way in the textarea from which it was submitted. The page itself is UTF-8 character encoding, but maybe the PHP script that sent the email can't handle UTF-8 characters. The email was sent to multiple addresses as a test. Some show the characters correctly, and some received-emails show the weird characters.

When I'm trying to analyze characters, what tool in Ubuntu will allow me to determine exactly what a character is (for both visible and invisible characters)?